# Java - syntax has me stumped

Tags: java, syntax

I think there are a few fundamental problems with my code here. I'm not too familiar with the java syntax, so I'm not too sure where I've gone wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use a constructor in the middle, and a few accessors towards the bottom, but I think I have over-complicated it for myself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class FerryBooking {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        class VehicleBooking {
            private String booking_ID = new String("");
            private String registration = new String("");
            private String make_model = new String("");
            private int number_passengers = 1;
            private boolean insurance_choice = false;
            private boolean insurance_flag = false;

            public static final int booking_fee= 100;
            public static final int extra_passenger = 50;
            public static final int insurance_fee = 50;

            VehicleBooking() {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("Enter booking ID");
                booking_ID = input.next();
                System.out.print("Enter registration number");
                registration = input.next();
                System.out.print("Enter vehicle make/model");
                make_model = input.next();
                System.out.print("Enter number of passengers");
                number_passengers = scan.nextInt();
            }

            public String getBookingID(){
                return booking_ID;
            }
            public String getRegistration(){
                return registration;
            }
            public String getMakeModel(){
                return make_model;
            }
            public int getPassengers(){
                return number_passengers;
            }
            public boolean getInsurance(){
                return insurance_choice;
            }
            public boolean addInsurance(){
                insurance_choice = true;
                if (insurance_flag = false) {
                    insurance_flag = true;
                    return true;
                } else if (insurance_flag = true) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            public double getBookingFee(){
                int final_cost = booking_fee + (getPassengers()*extra_passenger);
                if (insurance_choice = true){
                    final_cost = final_cost + insurance_fee;
                }
                return final_cost;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**--EDIT--**

I have re-written a lot of the code, and sized it down to where my big issue was; the constructor. However I am getting an error related to the constructor with the code provided to me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VehicleBooking {

    private String booking_ID = "";
    private String registration = "";
    private String make_model = "";
    private int number_passengers = 1;
    private boolean insurance_choice = false;

    public static final int BOOKING_FEE= 100;
    public static final int EXTRA_PASSENGER = 50;
    public static final int INSURANCE_FEE = 50;

    public VehicleBooking(String booking_ID1, String registration1,  String make_model1, int number_passengers1) {

        /** Initialise the variables **/
        booking_ID = booking_ID1;
        registration = registration1; 
        make_model = make_model1;
        number_passengers = number_passengers1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        VehicleBooking vb = new VehicleBooking(booking_ID1, registration1, make_model1, number_passengers1);
    }       
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create more than one wrapper for the same stream as this will lead to confusion and bugs.  Also `new String("")` is much the same as `""` or not setting the Strings at all.

Comment: There are a few issues. One of them: comparisons in Java use `==`, not `=`: `if (insurance_flag = false)` => `if (insurance_flag == false)`. Which in turn can be written: `if (!insurance_flag)`.

Comment: Are you getting errors? First thing I can see is that in getBookingFee you need two = and not one =. At the moment you are assigning insurance_choice to true not checking equality

Comment: You're declaring a named class *within the `main` method*. While that's *valid*, it's generally a really bad idea. Extract the class out first, then see if you're still confused.

Comment: I don't see any benefit to declaring a class inside of `main()`.  If you *have* to use a nested class, then it would be better to do so outside of `main()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First don't initialize a String like the one below: -

```
private String booking_ID = new String("");
```

Rather use `String.valueOf()` or just assign an empty string to variable:  -

```
private String booking_ID = "";
```

Second, make a habit to declare your `CONSTANTS` with `UPPER_CASE` letter:  -

```
public static final int BOOKING_FEE = 100;
```

Third, take a look at your constructor: -

```
    VehicleBooking()  {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter booking ID");
        booking_ID = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter registration number");
        registration = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter vehicle make/model");
        make_model = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter number of passengers");
        number_passengers = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

You should never do `I/O` operation in your constructor.. `Constructors` are used to initialize the state of the object. It's sole purpose is to `initialize`.

For I/O purpose, make different method `readInput()` and call it after your object is created..

**Another thing: -**  Here's your `if-else-if` block you have used..

```
         if (insurance_flag = false) {
             insurance_flag = true;
             return true;
         } else if (insurance_flag = true) {
             return false;
         }
```

In this code, your `if` is always `false` and your `else if` is always `true`.. Because you are actually assigning these `values` to your `insurance_flag`.. You should use `==` for comparison purpose..

So, use **`if (insurance_flag == false)`**..  In fact you don't need to compare with a boolean literal...

just use: - **`if (!insurance_flag)`**.. They are equivalent..

Ideally you should change that method containing your above if to the one below: -

```
       public boolean addInsurance(){
            boolean returnValue = !insurance_flag;
            insurance_flag = true;
            return returnValue;
       }
```

Because that is what your method is doing, but in an odd way..

You can also replace **`final_cost = final_cost + insurance_fee;`** with the below code: -

```
final_cost += insurance_fee;
```

By using it this way, `final_cost` will not be evaluated `twice`..

EDIT ** : -

Your `constructor` should look like this: -

```
public VehicleBooking(String bookingId, String registration, String makeModel, 
                      String numberOfPassengers)  {

    /** Initialize the instance variables **/
    /** this represent the reference to current object **/
    this.booking_ID = bookingId;
    this.registration = registration; 
    this.make_model = makeModel;
    this.number_passengers = numberOfPassengers;
}
```

So, you're actually passing those values you read, into the constructor as parameter, and initializing your instance attributes, with those parameters..

I think this would clear your doubt..

Comment: +1 but you should **never** compare with a boolean literal anyway. Just use `if (condition)` or `if (! condition)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph.. Oh yeah... Will Edit

Comment: That's not quite what `if(insurance_flag)` is doing - If it's already set to `true` it remains like that. Maybe rewrite it as `public boolean addInsurance() { boolean ret = !insurance_flag; insurance_flag = true; return ret; }`

Comment: The insurance part is for something to come in later code. It was really confusing in the specification i'm following, but i'm fairly sure the insurance method is working as intended.

Comment: @Dean Apologies, my comment was directed at @Rohit, because his `addInsurance()` method doesn't have the same functionality as your original code.

Comment: @RohitJain In your answer, you mentioned not doing I/O within a constructor. My spec states "Implement a constructor for the  VehicleBooking class which accepts the  booking ID, 
registration number,  vehicle description and number of  people travelling in the vehicle  as 
parameters and stores the supplied information in the corresponding instance variables"

I don't understand why the spec would ask for a constructor here when it seems as if I could do everything outside the constructor with a lot less code? Unless I'm missing something here

Comment: @Dean. According to your specs, you need to pass those values as `Constructor` parameters, and set them to the `instance` variables of your class.. That is what I said, a constructor should do.. So, you need to read those values at some method, and from that method, invoke your `constructor` passing them as parameters, such that your `object` is initialized..

Comment: @Dean.. I have added an ideal constructor at the end of my post.. You can take a look at that.. Probably you would be clear..

Comment: @RohitJain So I decided to come back to this spec and try to fix what was going wrong with my constructor. I used your code but it is giving me an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK.. I saw your error.. You have declared your constructor inside your `main()` method.. Place it outside your main().. You should never ever declare a `constructor` or another method inside a method...   **`NESTED METHODS are NOT ALLOWED in Java`**

Comment: @RohitJain When I move the constructor out of the main method, it says it cannot resolve booking_ID, registration, etc. This is why I assumed you could nest methods. How do I get the constructor to recognise these variables?

Comment: @Dean.. That is because, you have kept your variable local to main.. You should have them as instance variable of class.. Outside every method.. I have modified your code.. Take a look at that and try to understand..

Comment: @RohitJain OK that was a silly mistake from me haha, I should have spotted that one. But with your revised code, I am left with an error in the main method now. Is this because I don't have any values going into the variables at the moment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17408/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-dean)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use

```
private String booking_ID = new String("");
```

You're creating a new empty immutable. You should at least let the JVM intern the blank string!

```
if (insurance_flag = false)
```

That's assignment, not evaluation, use ==, better still just if (!insurance_flag)

```
    public boolean addInsurance(){
        insurance_choice = true;
        if (insurance_flag = false) {
            insurance_flag = true;
            return true;
         } else if (insurance_flag = true) {
            return false;
         }
        return true;
    }
```

This entire function doesn't make a lot of sense, you've coded in circles. Just set Insurance flag to true. Insurance_flag isn't used anywhere aside from the return... Why would you want to return true only on the first setting of the flag? Just make it void. for a "setting" action.

Also, you're munging make and model together into one string, not really a very OO way of constructing your item. Ideally, you should attach a Vehicle object to your VehicleBooking rather than attributes of a Vehicle itself.

Ditch the inner classes and don't perform the input in the constructor. Construct FROM the input (i.e. pass it in) or use a builder.